# Having problems with black jack card game in java

Tags: java

I posted this earlier and the majority of my questions were answered but I am just having 1 last error in my code.

SO basically I am making a game of black jack in java. I have a card class, a deck class and my main. The problem I am having is in my main. In my deck class I create a deck of 52 cards in an arraylist. I then have a method deal that will take the top card and add it into the hand arraylist which is the cards that are in the users hands. Once the user doesn't want to continue anymore the cards stop being dealt. The very last part of my main takes the values in the hand arraylist and adds them up and compares them to 21 to see if the user went over or not. I realize that I am trying to hold a Card value in the int total but what would I use to hold the values in the arraylist so that I can compare them? Any help/suggestions or advice is appreciated

the error that I'm getting on this code is this:

```
 1 error found:
File: E:\Documents\Java Files\Assignment 3\CardGameTester.java  [line: 33]
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Card to int
```

the part of my main that is in question is this:

```
int total;

for(int index = 0; index <= hand.size(); index++)
{
  total = hand.get(index);
}

System.out.println("Your total value for you cards are: " + total);

if(total == 21){
  System.out.println("Congrats, you have won for not going over 21");
}
else
  {
    System.out.println("Sorry, you lose for going over 21");
}
```

for anyone who is curious here is my Card and Deck classes:

```
public class Card
{
  private int rankValue, suitValue;
  private String ranks[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
  private String suits[] = {"Ace", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

  public Card(int rank, int suit)
  {
    rankValue = rank;
    suitValue = suit;
  }

  public String convertToString(int rank){
    return ranks[rank];
  }

  public void setRank(int rank){
    rankValue = rank;
  }

  public void setSuit(int suit){
    suitValue = suit;
  }

  public int getRank(){
    return rankValue;
  }

  public int getSuit(){
    return suitValue;
  }

  public String toString(){
    String name = ranks[rankValue] + " of " + suits[suitValue];
    return name;
  }
}
```

Deck class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck
{
  private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

  public Deck()
  {
    for(int a = 1; a <= 4; a++)
    {
      for(int b = 1; b <= 13; b++)
      {
        Card c = new Card(a,b);
        cards.add(c);
      }
    }
    shuffle();
  }

  public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(cards);
  }

  public Card deal(){
    int index = 0;
    Card c = cards.remove(index);
    index++;
    return c;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"1 last error in my code"*  Wish I had $5 for every time I heard that.  ;)

Comment: What does `hand.get(index)` return? I suspect it's a `Card` but you're trying to assign it to an `int`.

Comment: index goes through the arraylist and for every spot that index goes to it will grab that card value and assign it to total. I realize that I am doing it wrong but I'm not sure the correct way to do it

Answer (score 2):

```
cannot convert from Card to int
```

The card class might have a `int value` field that is accessed by `getValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Card` class should have a method called something like `intValue` or `getValue` to get the integer value of the card. Then call it on every card and add up the returned numbers. Dealing with soft aces will be a little tricky though.

Also, use foreach, rather than manual indexing.

```
int total;
for(Card card: hand)
{
   total += card.value();
}
```

Comment: for this I am supposed to have things converted to a string value. So in my card class I have two string arrays, one for suit and one for rank. Would the method you're talking about be betting off in the deck class? I edited in my card and deck class also if you wanted to have a look

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you that a Card is not an "int", which of course is perfectly true. I would suggest that you read up about object oriented programming. The basic idea is classes contain properties which may be simple types like int or other instances of other classes. Different classes have different sets of operations and properties. The compiler knows that a Card has certain operations and for that reference only allows Cards or something that looks like a Card. I dont want to go into further details as there are many great discussions and tutorials on the internet that can easily be found.